# How would you proof a new set of equations for generating pythagorean triples?

Tags: proof-writing, pythagorean-triples

I was studying Pythagorean triples for the GRE and I noticed a simple arithmetic pattern for the *a* terms. This led me to look for patterns for the *b* and *c* terms. I found that evens and odds follow different patterns, but it seems like all odds follow one set of patterns, and all evens another.

Using these patterns, I found a method for generating two unknown terms from a single known term.  This is something I haven't seen before, so I want to check if my algorithms are always right, and I also want to check to make sure they don't skip over or miss any triples.  (i.e. check for false positives and false negatives)

To do so, I built a simple table in Excel using calculated columns and generated the first 100 sets of *a, b, c* for both series (evens and odds). Now, things seem to check out when I spot-check my outputs against lists of P.Triples I've found online, but I don't have time to sit here and check every term--I need to study!! (test tomorrow)

So, how could I quickly and rigorously "proof" this theory??

Here are my algorithms:

***For ODDS:*** 
$$a_n=1+2n$$
$$b_n=(a_n-1)(n+1)$$
$$c_n=b_n+1$$

***For EVENS:*** 
$$a_n=4+2n$$
$$b_n=(a_n/2+1)(n+1)$$
$$c_n=b_n+2$$

Comment: Just looking at the "Odds" case, isn't $a_n\,\pmod 2$ always $1$?  Your triple  is $(1+2n, 2n^2+2n, 2n^2+2n+1)$ which can easily be shown the be a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: But this won't get every triple, e.g., $15,8,17$ is not of that form.

Comment: In the even case, the formula does not seem to give a pythagorean triple.

Comment: @myerson - it gets 8,15,17

Comment: I don't know how to upload a table, or I could post the results from Excel...

Comment: @Peter - could you provide an example where it does not result in a Pythagorean triple? I added another column in Excel to compare the results of a^2+b^2 against c^2, and in both series, the sum of a^2 and b^2 = c^2 tests positive for all sets generated.

Comment: Set $n=1$, and you get $(4,6,8)$ , which is not a pythagorean triple.

Comment: The formula for the odd numbers is correct, I assume you made a typo by writing it down in the even case.

Comment: I bet you're right. I'll look at my worksheet next time I'm at my computer, because that has the right results. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: The typo was in the definition of a_n for the evens--the constant value is 4, not 2.

Comment: How about $20,21,29$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Hey Gerry, yes, I'm still around. I just haven't had much time to look further into this. So, is the only way to prove that this doesn't miss certain sets to basically go through all possible known sets and compare?  No faster/more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm does not generate all primitive Pythagorean triples. The table below is a sample of the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2,x\in\mathbb{N}$. In the table, you can see that your first algorithm generates only $Set_1$ and your second algorithm generates only the first column of triples with $A,B$ reversed.

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
\end{array}
You will note that $A$ can be any odd number greater than one, that $B$ can be any multiple of four, and that $C$ always takes the form of $4x+1$. The formula that generates these table "elements" is.
\begin{equation}
  A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\\ B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{equation}
If we set $n=1$ for $Set_1$, we get

\begin{equation}
  A=2k+1\qquad B=2k^2+2k\qquad C=2 k^2 + 2 k + 1
\end{equation}
If we let $k=1$ for $Column_1$, we get
$$A=4n^2-1\qquad B=4n\qquad C=4n^2+1$$

I believe these simplified formulas generate the same triples as your formulas.

It is a simple exercise from here to prove $A^2+B^2=C^2$, that $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2$, and that, if the interval between values of $A$ is other than $(2n-1)k$, that the functions for $B$ and $C$ derived from the Pythagorean theorem will produce non-integers for most combinations of $(n,k)\cdots$ meaning that the formula as presented it missing no primitive triples.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Lulu's comment, I think this is how you would prove this.

Here's the proof for the **odds**:
$$a_n^2=(2n+1)(2n+1)=4n^2+4n+1$$
$$b_n=(1+2n-1)(n+1)=2n(n+1)=2(n^2+n)$$
$$b_n^2=(2(n^2+n))^2=4(n^2+n)(n^2+n)=4n^4+8n^3+4n^2$$
$$a_n^2+b_n^2=4n^4+8n^3+8n^2+4n+1$$
$$c_n=2(n^2+n)+1=2(n^2+n+1/2)$$
$$c_n^2=4(n^2+n+1/2)(n^2+n+1/2)=4n^4+8n^3+8n^2+4n+1$$

So, $a_n^2+b_n^2=c_n^2$, which I think proves it's correct.

And here's the proof for the **evens**:
$$a_n^2=(2n+4)(2n+4)=4n^2+16n+16$$
$$b_n=((2n+4)/2+1)(n+1)=(n+3)(n+1)=n^2+4n+3$$
$$b_n^2=(n^2+4n+3)^2=4(n^2+4n+3)(n^2+4n+3)=n^4+8n^3+22n^2+24n+9$$
$$a_n^2+b_n^2=n^4+8n^3+26n^2+40n+25$$
$$c_n=n^2+4n+5$$
$$c_n^2=(n^2+4n+5)(n^2+4n+5)=n^4+8n^3+26n^2+40n+25$$

Again, $a_n^2+b_n^2=c_n^2$, which I think proves both sets of equations will always give a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Extremely closely related question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655878/proof-verification-for-set-of-equations-for-generating-pythagorean-triples

Comment: This maybe a topic better suited to the meta board--but I was afraid that the question had morphed from "how would I write a proof for something" to "could someone help me verify this proof" and I didn't want to do so much editing as to make the original comments on this question become invalid so I posted the second question. If that was wrong, let me know and I can delete the second question...

Comment: I don't think it was wrong to post the second question, but I do think that when two questions are so closely related it's mandatory to link each one to the other. So, that's what I did.