# Proof verification for set of equations for generating Pythagorean triples

Tags: solution-verification, pythagorean-triples

Just looking for verification on this...

Here are my algorithms:

***For ODDS:*** 
$$a_n=1+2n$$
$$b_n=(a_n-1)(n+1)$$
$$c_n=b_n+1$$

***For EVENS:*** 
$$a_n=4+2n$$
$$b_n=(a_n/2+1)(n+1)$$
$$c_n=b_n+2$$

Here's the proof for the **odds**:
$$a_n^2=(2n+1)(2n+1)=4n^2+4n+1$$
$$b_n=(1+2n-1)(n+1)=2n(n+1)=2(n^2+n)$$
$$b_n^2=(2(n^2+n))^2=4(n^2+n)(n^2+n)=4n^4+8n^3+4n^2$$
$$a_n^2+b_n^2=4n^4+8n^3+8n^2+4n+1$$
$$c_n=2(n^2+n)+1=2(n^2+n+1/2)$$
$$c_n^2=4(n^2+n+1/2)(n^2+n+1/2)=4n^4+8n^3+8n^2+4n+1$$

You can see $a_n^2+b_n^2=c_n^2$, which I think proves it's correct.

And here's the proof for the **evens**:
$$a_n^2=(2n+4)(2n+4)=4n^2+16n+16$$
$$b_n=((2n+4)/2+1)(n+1)=(n+3)(n+1)=n^2+4n+3$$
$$b_n^2=(n^2+4n+3)^2=4(n^2+4n+3)(n^2+4n+3)=n^4+8n^3+22n^2+24n+9$$
$$a_n^2+b_n^2=n^4+8n^3+26n^2+40n+25$$
$$c_n=n^2+4n+5$$
$$c_n^2=(n^2+4n+5)(n^2+4n+5)=n^4+8n^3+26n^2+40n+25$$

Again, $a_n^2+b_n^2=c_n^2$, which I think proves both sets of equations will always result in a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Extremely closely related question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655103/how-would-you-proof-a-new-set-of-equations-for-generating-pythagorean-triples

Comment: I developed a formula from observations of this table.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & Triple_1 & Triple_2 & Triple_3 & Triple_4  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41\\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65\\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Can you generate all the primitives from a single variable?

Comment: @Poetasis--Checked against the output from my worksheet, I get the entire first row in your table, then just the $Triple_1$ entries for the rest of the rows.  I'm missing:  (21,20,29) (27,36,45) (33,56,65) (28,45,53) (48,55,73) (65,72,97) (77,36,85) (91,60,109) (105,88,137).  Is there a good resource for a table like this with *all* known primitives?

Comment: My formula generates all Pythagorean triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2x-1)^2,x\in\mathbb{N}$ (which includes all primitives). I couldn't figure out how do it with a single variable except for $Set_1$ and all first members of all sets.

$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$ BTW, I've search and searched but the formula and these sets appear to be an original discovery by me. It took millions of spreadsheet cells to find it but it works and I'm writing paper on it.

Comment: You can generate exactly what YOU found by setting $n=1$ to find the first row or setting $k=1$ to find the first column. The latter resolves to $$A=4n^2-1\qquad B=4nn\qquad C=4n^2+1$$

Comment: The first row and the fist column contain all primitives but all other rows contain a non-primitive whenever $k$ is multiple of any factor of $(2n-1)$ such as $Triple_3$ [$F(2,3)$] of $Set_2$ where $(2n-1)=3$ and $(27,36,45)=3^2\times(3,4,5)$.